# GNOME 3: How to display status of multiple batteries?

Tags: gnome3, battery

T400, Debian Jessie, GNOME 3.14

How can I see both batteries (main and ultrabay) when clicking on the battery icon?

I looked for a suitable extension on http://extensions.gnome.org/ , but I didn't find any.

Comment: I don't think there's any option for that - as far as I know gnome creates a virtual "composite battery" (via the settings daemon power plugin - it sort of sums batteries capacities) and will show the aggregate value.